# SDL Web 8 CU1 Update | single machine i| microservice installation error

Tags: microservices, web8

I am performing comulative upgrade from web8 to web 8.1.1. When I try to install microservices using the command

> .quickinstall.ps1 -license FILE -enable-discovery -enable-deployer -enable-preview -enable-session

I am getting Tcp connection timeout error[image]

Here is the error logs -

> 2016-05-06 13:18:39,056 ERROR SpringApplication - Application startup failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queryServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/SDLWeb_Services/session/services/content-service/content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar!/com/sdl/web/content/odata/query/service/QueryServiceImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationRepositoryMonitor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientSocketException: Could not initiate connection to the endpoint.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1101) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) ~[spring-boot-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:1.2.5.RELEASE]
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.start(WinServiceContainer.java:29) [service-container-core-8.1.1-1007.jar:8.1.1-1007]
>       at com.sdl.delivery.service.WinServiceContainer.main(WinServiceContainer.java:46) [service-container-core-8.1.1-1007.jar:8.1.1-1007]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationRepositoryMonitor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientSocketException: Could not initiate connection to the endpoint.
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       ... 15 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationRepositoryMonitor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sdl.odata.client.api.exception.ODataClientSocketException: Could not initiate connection to the endpoint.
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.SpringContentDeliveryKernel.ensureInitialised(SpringContentDeliveryKernel.java:38) ~[cd_core-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.registerKernel(KernelFactory.java:40) ~[cd_core-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.tridion.cd.core.kernel.KernelFactory.getKernel(KernelFactory.java:27) ~[cd_core-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getComponent(StorageManagerFactory.java:70) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getStorageManager(StorageManagerFactory.java:49) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:176) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.getDefaultDAO(StorageManagerFactory.java:99) ~[cd_datalayer-8.1.1-1005.jar:8.1.1-1005]
>       at com.sdl.web.content.odata.query.service.QueryServiceImpl.(QueryServiceImpl.java:37) ~[content-common-8.1.1-1008.jar:8.1.1-1008]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147) ~[spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
>       ... 17 common frames omitted

If anybody has the context about this error?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Malee for the reply. It has been resolved. It was due to wrong SQL Server password in setenv.ps1 configuration file which I have corrected to make it run

Answer (score 4):

In our case, port 8081 is used for something else, so it is not available for deployer service. Therefore we did not use quickinstall script. We install each service separately. Before you run installService.ps1 for each service, you can edit the script and change to your port number and run it.

Comment: Thanks Malee for the reply. It has been resolved. It was due to wrong SQL Server password in setenv.ps1 configuration file which I have corrected to make it run